# Convert D string to C char*

Tags: c++, c, d, dmd

Well, basically that's what I need :

- I've got an `extern`(al) `char *` variable
- I want to assign the value of a D string

**Code :**

```
import std.stdio;
import std.string;
import core.stdc.stdlib;

extern (C) int yyparse();
extern (C) extern __gshared FILE* yyin;
extern (C) extern __gshared char* yyfilename;

void main(string[] args)
{
    string filename = args[1];

    auto file = File(filename, "r");

    yyfilename = toStringz(filename);
    yyin = file.getFP();

    yyparse();
}
```

However, the `toStringz` function returns this error :

```
main.d(15): Error: cannot implicitly convert expression (toStringz(filename)) of type immutable(char)* to char*
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: I don't know D at all, but the "immutable" part suggests that a well-placed `const` might fix it. Maybe `extern (C) extern __gshared const char* yyfilename`?

Comment: `const(char)* yyfilename` is the syntax you'll want here - a mutable pointer to constant data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `yyfilename`, and the return value of `toStringz` when it is passed a string, have different const qualifiers. `filename` is immutable (D `string` is an alias to `immutable(char)[]`), however `yyfilename` does not have any const qualifier, and is thus mutable.

You have two options:

1. If you know that `yyfilename` will not bemodified elsewhere in your program, you should declare it as `const(char)*` instead of `char*`.
2. Otherwise, you should create a copy of `filename` when converting it: `toUTFz!(char*)(filename)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I decided to choose this one as the answer since (although both *work*) this to address the main point in a more efficient way. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
import std.utf;

void main()
{
    string filename;
    char* yyfilename;
    yyfilename = toUTFz!(char*)(filename);
    // yyfilename = filename.toUTFz!(char*);  // or with UFCS syntax
}
```

Comment: Yes, yes, yes! That was it. (Well, it's obvious I have to brush up my humble D skills...) Thanks a lot! :-)